Swift extension to an ObjC class inside the same framework
My team creates an xcframework, let's call it MyFramework. The framework uses just one class as an API, also called MyFramework. Until now, this framework has only contained ObjC code. However, we want to add a Swift file to support some SwiftUI stuff. In this Swift file, I want to add an extension to the MyFramework class.
In my Swift file, I have something simple, like
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public extension MyFramework {
    func doStuff() { /// }
}

However, this doesn't build because the swift file can't find MyFramework. I experimented with adding a bridging header, which allows the framework to build. However, this doesn't seem to generate a .swiftinterface file, which means a test app can't find the doStuff() function. In further investigation, it seems that bridging headers aren't permitted in frameworks? I attempted to manually construct a .swiftinterface file, with no success.
I then enabled Build Libraries for Distribution, which seems to be recommended for this situation. However, this requires that the bridging header be removed, which means that the swift file can't find MyFramework again. Online reading suggests that a modulemap is supposed to fix this, but I already have a modulemap, which looks like
framework module MyFramework {
    umbrella header "MyFramework.h"

    export *
}

But this doesn't seem to affect the build at all. My understanding of modulemaps may be flawed, but I thought they were intended to expose ObjC code to Swift APPS, not necessarily when building the framework in the first place.
Does anyone have any advice on how I can do this? I could resort to creating a separate framework for the swift portion, but I'd really rather not do that if at all possible.

What does the error say? You need to have a bridging header "MyFramework-Bridge.h" and import "MyFramework.h" in it (don't forget to declare bridging header in target settings). No modulemap/umbrella needed, just bridging header
